# How to use another algorithm when the first approach is too slow?

Tags: programming, abort

I need to write a program that uses an alternate algorithm when the algorithm first attempted is taking too long. Here is a minimal example.

```
foo[n_Integer]:=CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[soln=FactorInteger[n],3],{{n,1}}];
foo[140]
(* {{2,2},{5,1},{7,1}} *)
```

The example above did what I expected. However, in the next example FactorInteger requires more than three seconds. In that case I wanted foo to return  {{n,1}} where (n=10^100+3). Instead I get $Aborted.

```
foo[10^100+3]
(* $Aborted *)
```

How do I get foo to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can just use TimeConstrained on its own:

```
foo[n_Integer] := TimeConstrained[FactorInteger[n], 3, {{n, 1}}]
```

Comment: Strange it works on this problem. When I tried this on a complicated application the kernel stops when the time-constraint is exceeded.